# Spring JPA and log4j version conflict

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, log4j, atmosphere

I'm trying to set up a Spring JPA Hibernate simple project with Atmosphere framework.

This is Maven dependency

```
    <!-- Spring framework -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.8.Final</version>
    </dependency> 
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.8.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.atmosphere</groupId>
        <artifactId>atmosphere-runtime</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.wimpi</groupId>
        <artifactId>telnetd-x</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1</version>
    </dependency> 
   <!-- Logging with SLF4J & LogBack -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.5</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.13</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
```

But i am getting version conflict with log4j and Spring hibernate JPA.

error trace:

```
 org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispactherServlet.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: TRACE
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1566)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)

Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: TRACE
at org.jboss.logging.Log4jLogger.translate(Log4jLogger.java:60)
at org.jboss.logging.Log4jLogger.doLog(Log4jLogger.java:40)
at org.jboss.logging.Logger.trace(Logger.java:107)
at org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.internal.StrategySelectorImpl.registerStrategyImplementor(StrategySelectorImpl.java:69)
at org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.internal.StrategySelectorBuilder.addDialect(StrategySelectorBuilder.java:248)
at org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.internal.StrategySelectorBuilder.addDialects(StrategySelectorBuilder.java:198)
at org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.internal.StrategySelectorBuilder.buildSelector(StrategySelectorBuilder.java:165)
at org.hibernate.boot.registry.BootstrapServiceRegistryBuilder.build(BootstrapServiceRegistryBuilder.java:253)
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.buildBootstrapServiceRegistry(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:520)
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:208)
```

Please help, thanks

Comment: Can you post your log4j configuration file in your question? and what is the version of log4j you are using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the log4j transitional dependency from telnetd-x:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.wimpi</groupId>
    <artifactId>telnetd-x</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.1</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

This lib is using an old version of Log4j (1.2.9) and it can be the source of your issues.